# Pourquoi ne dit-on pas "des articles de journal" ?

Tags: accord, compléments

Pourquoi dit-on "des articles de journa**ux**" et pas "des articles de journa**l**" ?
C'est une bizarrerie d'usage non ?

Car on dit bien "des briques de ciment", "des grues de chantier", "des feux de forêt" -> le complément ne [s'accorde pas quand il référence une classe](https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-78229.php)

Pourtant je me rends compte que quand je parle je dis naturellement "il écrit des articles de journaux".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Après avoir googlé un peu, l'on voit que toutes les deux formes sont d'usage courant (article de journal/journaux). Par ailleurs, concernant l'accord en nombre du complément du nom...

> Il n’existe pas de règle clairement établie en ce qui concerne
>   l’accord en nombre du complément du nom, comme dans les exemples des
>   chefs de service(s) ou une salle de bain(s). L’usage est flottant. Il
>   faut généralement analyser chaque cas séparément et se demander si le
>   complément évoque l’idée d’un seul élément ou, au contraire, l’idée de
>   plusieurs éléments. [Source, accompagnée par une pléthore d'examples.](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/clefsfp/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_catlog_c&page=94AapvV1Dbzs)

Toutefois, selon une recherche plus approfondie sur [Ngram](http://ttps://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=articles%20de%20journal%2Carticles%20de%20journaux&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Carticles%20de%20journal%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Carticles%20de%20journaux%3B%2Cc0) (merci @[Luke](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/12688/luke-sawczak)), l'on peut voir que pour le cas en question, la seconde option est plus fréquente.

Comment: [Toutefois](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=articles+de+journal%2Carticles+de+journaux&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Carticles%20de%20journal%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Carticles%20de%20journaux%3B%2Cc0) ...

Comment: Merci encore ! Je l'ai ajouté.

Answer (score 2):

Dans cette expression, les articles proviennent de plusieurs journaux. *Des articles de journal* écorche un peu l'oreille, mais n'est pas complètement exclu (2 % des occurrences contre 98 % pour le pluriel).

Quand la singularité du complément est exclue, le singulier l'est aussi :

> *Des marchands de journaux* - *Des marchands de <s>journal</s>*
>
> *Des courses de chevaux* - *Des courses de <s>cheval</s>*

Quand la singularité est possible, on rencontre les deux formes avec des fréquences souvent comparables :

> *Des selles de cheval* - *Des selles de chevaux*
>
> *Des pages de journal* - *Des pages de journaux*
>
> *Des récifs de corail* - *Des récifs de coraux*

Comment: On retrouve ça dans "travail d'intérêt général" et "travaux d'intérêt général/aux" pourtant travaux d'intérêt généraux ne veux absolument rien dire ! Comme quoi, tout fout le camp ! 

Comment: @SteffX Il faudrait condamner les perpétrateurs de tels outrages à un travail d'intérêts généraux ;-)